# Discuss going back to project I asked to be removed from

Tags: communication

I requested multiple times to be moved from Project A to Project B. I have been working on Project B for a while now and would like to move back to Project A.

**STORY**

I joined my current job, as a Software Developer, straight out of college. After the initial training period, I was assigned to a team which dealt with Client Side issues (front-end, emails, payments etc.)

I had no prior knowledge of front-end engineering and thought it would be a good opportunity to learn on the job. A few months into it, I realised that the tasks that were being handled by me did not spike my interest and told my manager that I wanted to switch teams citing that I did not fancy the current role and would like to move to a more technical role. 
He told me to that they couldn't move me immediately and asked me to delve deeper till the time they could in the hope that it would eventually grow on me. 3 months later I was asked for my feedback and it had not changed. I was moved to a different team.

I have been in the current team for about 6 months and a new team is now going to be working on a re-architecture of project A which I am very much interested in.

How to communicate to my manager that I would like to move to the new team? I already got what I asked for initially, a more technical role, and I would be flip-flopping in this situation.

Comment: Is it really fair to consider "a re-architecture of project A" as being the same as "project A"? They sound like two very different things to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by doing some due diligence.  I would talk to the Project Manager, team lead and people on the team that will be involved and find out if the direction they are wanting to take is something that will be interesting.  Then get a couple allies on the new team that want you to join and get them to help lobby for your inclusion.

If you are still interested then have a conversation with the manager. I would explain that you have the background and experience with the project that would make you an asset in the architecture redesign and would like to be involved with that portion of the project even if its just a few hours a week.

As a manager my concern would be that you would come back on the project, and the team makes a decision you do not like, you are just going to want off the team again.   If you came to me and asked to switch back completely, then I am more likely to deny your request. I would be concerned that you do not like the team you are working on now either and that is going to make me think you may not be a good fit for any team.  So start slow, build some relationships with the new project team, while continuing with your current work.  If you do well then your manager should approach you about moving to the new project team or increasing your role.

Answer (score 5):

> How to communicate to my manager that I would like to move back to my
>   previous team?

Just talk.

Explain why you would like to move to Team A and what you would do to lessen the potential impact on your current Team B.

> I already got what I asked for initially, a more technical role, and I
>   would be flip-flopping in this situation.

Yes, you would be flip-flopping.

Only you can know if this means your manager will start to view you as a high-maintenance type who will never be happy. That's a risk in making repeated requests to move to different teams.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you happy is not of primary importance to most companies.  So you are going to need to find a argument that explains why having you on the other team will provide a benefit to the business, and a greater benefit to the business than where you are.

If you can come up with reasons why and how the company will benefit by having you back on the original team, you simply go to the manager and explain them.  Then listen (don't argue!).  If the manager has good reasons to counteract your reasons, you won't be moved.  If your reasons are good enough, then there is a good chance you will be.